Is my understanding of the GitFlow release process valid?
We currently use the GitFlow process to manage our releases (or so I think) for a native iOS app.
Here are the steps we carried out for context:
We created a new repo with the main branch
We then branched off a develop branch from main
We then branch off several feature branches so engineers can work on features independently and then we merge them back into develop
When we are ready to do a release we create a release branch from develop, lets say release-1.0.0
This release branch builds a version of the app which is then sent to our QA engineers who test the app and share any minor fixes needed which are carried out on the release branch
Once everything looks good, we create a PR to merge release into main. Once the PR is approved, we merge release into main and tag it with v1.0.0
We then open another PR to merge release into develop and then delete the release branch.
This all seemed to work well when we had the first version as main had no code on it, however, now for the next app update, I am facing some issues in my understanding with gitflow.
Everything starts out the same with us creating a release branch off develop called release-1.1.0
Now my first question is that I notice the status of my main branch in relation to develop - it says This branch is 1 commit ahead of, 24 commits behind develop.
The 24 behind makes sense as there were 24 new commits to develop of feature branches, however, the 1 ahead is not so clear to me.
It could be because there were 2 seperate commits when merging release-1.0.0 into main and then a different one to merge release into develop - is this a normal state to be in when using GitFlow.
And now because of the main branch being in this state, when we want to merge release 1.1.0 into main, we are unable to because they are not in sync.
If we try to rebase 1.1.0 on to main, that won't work as it will overwrite the release branches with the old code on main.
We can't rebase main as this branch is protected and needs PR approvals to be merged into.
So please can someone help with answering:
1 - Is the state of the main branch possible in gitflow as I explained above ?
2 - How can we merge release into main when they are not in sync in the gitflow way ? Or another way to phrase this question - what is the right strategy to resolve merge conflicts that arise between main and release ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


Now my first question is that I notice the status of my main branch in
relation to develop - it says This branch is 1 commit ahead of, 24
commits behind develop.
The 24 behind makes sense as there were 24 new commits to develop of
feature branches, however, the 1 ahead is not so clear to me.
It could be because there were 2 seperate commits when merging
release-1.0.0 into main and then a different one to merge release into
develop - is this a normal state to be in when using GitFlow.

You're correct. Because there are two different commits - one into main and one into develop, it looks like the branches are different. If you diff between the contents of the two branches, however, you should see that the files are the same.
This is not an uncommon problem in the GitFlow model.

How can we merge release into main when they are not in sync in the
gitflow way ? Or another way to phrase this question - what is the
right strategy to resolve merge conflicts that arise between main and
release ?

One solution would be to merge from the release branch into main and then merge main into develop. You can apply the version tag in the release branch before merging or in main after merging.
Another solution would be to eliminate main. This is a more significant deviation from GitFlow, but applying your protections to the release branches instead of main would give you tighter control over what changes go into a release and reduce the overhead of maintaining an extra branch. Everything would be the same, except you would apply your tag to the release branch and then merge it back into develop to ensure that all your release fixes are in place for future releases.

Thanks Thomas. The first solution seems something I need to discuss with the team because it's a process that's being followed before I got here. While your point of merging main into develop seems like it would solve the issue (atleast in the future - now we are stuck with release / main merge conflict) - looking at gitflow documentation - there never seems to be this mentioned that we merge main into develop. It's always release that gets merged into both main and develop and then we delete the main branch. So this is what confuses me.

@ShawnFrank I'm guessing your comment has a mistake - you delete the release branch and not the main branch (this is what you say in the question). In GitFlow, the main branch is long-lived. But that doesn't matter. You shouldn't typically have conflicts between the main and develop branches, even if one is a commit ahead. If you have conflicts, something else is going on. Perhaps more recent changes in the develop branch are causing them. If your develop branch for release+1, that could be an issue whenever you merge the release branch into develop, too.

My mistake in the comment - can't edit sadly - delete the release branch is what I meant. So release now has conflicts with main and develop. I actually understand the develop side because lets say we created the release branch on 20 Dec and we want to merge release back into develop today, there are conflicts because in the last 6 days we added new features on develop that we didn't want to be part of the release. So now rebasing release onto develop before merging back to develop works fine. However, we can't do this to solve conflicts between release and main.

@ShawnFrank There should never be conflicts between release and main. If you released 1.4, the last commit on main should be the merge from the 1.4 release branch into main. If your release branch is 1.5 or 2.0, it should contain everything in main plus additional changes. The merge should take everything in the release branch as the source of truth. The only conflicts could be between your release branch (and maybe main, after merging your release branch into it) and develop. Let's say develop is deprecating or heavily refactoring a feature. This could cause conflicts.


It could be because there were 2 seperate commits when merging release-1.0.0 into main and then a different one to merge release into develop - is this a normal state to be in when using GitFlow.

Sounds like that is the issue. Main has merge commit a and develop has merge commit b. If that is the case, it's really not a problem. But it can be easily solved by merging the release branch to main and then merging main into develop after a release, instead of merging the release branch into both seperately.
So, Question 1: yes, see above
Question 2: There shouldn't be merge conflicts. If there are, you're releasing something other than the code that's on main right now. Make sure develop is up to date with main before making a release branch.
If there actually are merge conflicts somehow (hotfixes?), you should solve them when merging main into develop, before you make a release branch and definitely before you start testing.

Thanks for chiming in Ivo. Merging main into develop does seem like it will resolve the issue (atleast in the future) - however, if I look at the gitflow documentation - this never happens. It is always release gets merged into main and develop and then the release branch is deleted hence I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

@ShawnFrank Other than the "main is 1 ahead of develop" message, there shouldn't be an issue though. If the 1 commit ahead is a merge commit and doesn't actually contain any code changes, you shouldn't be getting merge conflicts.
